Next.js conditional rendering on small screens
I'm using a custom hook to render different elements on the page based on the screen size.
Hovewer during rendering there is a delay because of the useEffect hook. Elements that are rendered conditionally only appear after a few milisec or 1 sec delay.
Is it expected or is there a better way to achive the same result?
const useMobile = () => {
    const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {

        const handleResize = () => {
            setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
        };

        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

        handleResize();

        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    }, [])

    if (!windowWidth) return false;

    return windowWidth <= 860;
}


I'm using this custom hook, and I would like to minimalize this delay.
Conditional rendering part:
const isSmallScreen = useMobile();
...
{isSmallScreen && <button onClick={toggleOpen}>NavTrigger</button>}



I usually handle these usecases with css media queries. it's faster and avoids extra rerenders.

Yes that's right. The only reason why I prefer this approach is that the element is completely removed from the DOM this way.

Try this one
  useEffect(() => {
    let timeoutId;

    const handleResize = () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
        }, 100); // Adjust the debounce delay as needed
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    handleResize();

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        clearTimeout(timeoutId); // Cleanup
    };
}, []);

